# Using Youtube API with ESP8266 = redirection problems

Tags: esp8266

I am using ESP8266 programmed from Arduino to get data from the Google Youtube API. API, of course, works great in a browser using URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=CHANNEL-ID&key=GOOGLE-API-KEY
```

The problem is that "gooogleapis.com" is not the location where from I would receive the answer to my HTTPS request, it comes from a different location. When above URL is entered, it is being redirected and request answer comes from another location.

So what happens on ESP8266 when I try to open that address(of course, with added proper channel ID and google key) is following:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1580
Date: Sun, 12 Mar 2017 14:40:18 GMT
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34"
Connection: close

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/youtube/v3/channels</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That���s all we know.</ins>
Done.
```

Which is the Google error page(you seen it!). This is my Arduino code:

```
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

const char* ssid     = "SSID";  // WiFi network name
const char* password = "pass"; // WiFi pass

const char* host = "googleapis.com"; // page I am trying to load
const char* fingerprint = "22 37 4D 58 43 F4 A1 24 12 71 2B 74 7A FC 36 FC 24 A0 F0 9D";

String ch_id = "CHANNEL ID";
String api_key = "API KEY";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  delay(10);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    delay(500);                        
    Serial.print(".");            
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi! Local IP address is: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  WiFiClientSecure client; 
  if (!client.connect(host, 443))
  {
    Serial.println("I am unable to connect to that page."); 
    return; 
  }

  if (client.verify(fingerprint, host)) {
    Serial.println("certificate OK");
  } else {
    Serial.println("certificate NOT OK");
  }

  String url = "/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=" + ch_id + "&key=" + api_key;

  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  delay(10);

  while (client.available()) {
    String linija = client.readStringUntil('\r'); 
    Serial.print(linija);
  }

  Serial.println("Done.");
}

void loop() { 
}
```

- How to find out to which site I am redirected?
- How to read that from ESP8266 and redirect the same data to new site?

Comment: 404 is not a redirect. You should get a 302 or 301. In that case there will also be a Location: header that contains the new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your browser you used `www.googleapis.com`, but in your code you used `googleapis.com`.

```
https://googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=CHANNEL-ID&key=GOOGLE-API-KEY
```

returns a 404 page.

Add `www.` to your host in code.

Comment: Perfect! Can't believe I missed something so trivial. Thank you very much - works now.